# How to run remote video like local video in augmented reality for ios

Tags: ios, augmented-reality

I am working on iOS augmented reality and just implemented `vuforia-videoplayback-ios-1-0-2`
from https://ar.qualcomm.at/sdk/ios

In case of local videos when marker is being detected, video overlayed over the marker only(video screen size increases with marker size does increase and vice-versa). But in case of remote image I gave the video link as filename instead of a video file(.mp4). It worked but video from web ran through iPhone build-in full screen player. I just want to make it overlayed over marker just like what occours in case of local videos.

I will be grateful if anyone help me to sort this out.

Comment: Can you help me how did you created the Markers ? I am able to test the demo app with the local video and Markers provided by vuforia.

Comment: Oh...Thnx for ur concern...I have figured it out earlier... in case of local file the app works fine and overlay video on marker but in case of remote file video will not be overlaid... 
But may be there could be a way to do overlay on marker in case of remote files but I didn't find anything...

Comment: Thanks for feedback.I need to play the video locally, but I am concerned with creating the marker, how it has to  be created , I mean through which tool etc?Rest, programming part I am clear.So, can you help me with markers ?

Comment: Sure..go to [https://developer.vuforia.com/] then make a registration. Then click Target Manager-> Create Database. After creating database, select the database and click Add Target. Next give ur Target Name, Target Type will be single image, Target size and choose the image u wanna make marker & hit add. Ur image will be accessed with stars[how good ur image will work as marker.]. U can make 50+ images as marker in one database. Then select the database and mark the images u wanna need in ur app as markers and hit Download Selected Targets. U will get a .dat and a .xml file in return.

Comment: Look into ur project & u will get a existing .dat and .xml file. Remove them & add those 2 files u have just downloaded.

Comment: Now goto VideoPlaybckAppdelegate.mm file in ur project. Change the datasetName and give here ur .xml file name in ur didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method.

Lastly, goto EAGLView.mm file. and find renderFrameQCAR method. U will find below code in there>>>
`int playerIndex = 0;    // stones
        
       if (strcmp(trackable->getName(), "chips") == 0)
        {
            playerIndex = 1;
        }`

>>>index 0 will automatically mark ur first marker. In index 1, remove "chips" and give ur second marker name existed in ur .xml file.
Follow it & u will find ur new markers working just fine.

Comment: If u wanna add more than 2 markers then please make a question and give me the link. Coz it wouldn't be possible to describe here. Good to know if u want this. Good Luck.

Comment: Sure ... thanks for your help..I will post and pass on the link, if there is anything  more.